# my geolocation for googlemap is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to develop a hybrid application using jQuery mobile and phonegap , I want to implement a googlemap with geolocation support .for that I have done some coding but while running the app it is just giving me an ajax loader and it is not stopping, Can anybody help me to find the error .. I have tried some jQuery mobile demos but none of them worked properly . giving my code below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title> Google maps </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
       <style>
#content {
    padding: 0;
    position : absolute; 
    top : 0;  
    right : 0; 
    bottom : 0;  
    left : 0;     
}
</style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&language=en"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/min/jquery.ui.map.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

            var mumbai = new google.maps.LatLng(19.075984,72.877656),
                mobileDemo = { 'center': '19.075984,72.877656', 'zoom': 15 },
                cityList = [
                    ['Bank ATM CST Road', 19.075984,72.877656, 1],
                    ['Bank ATM Air India Road', 19.078318,72.877024, 2],
               ['Bank ATM Lal Bahadur Sasthri Road', 19.069236,72.875278, 3]
                             ];

            function initialize()
            {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': mobileDemo.center, 'zoom': mobileDemo.zoom, 'disableDefaultUI':false });
             //addMarkers();
      getcurrentposition();
            }

            function addMarkers()
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < cityList.length; i++) 
                {
                    var $marker = $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {id: i, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2],cityList[i][3]),title: cityList[i][0]});
                    $marker.click(function() {
                        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': cityList[this.id][0]}, this);
                    });
                }
            }

            $(document).on("pageinit", "#basic-map", function() {
                initialize();
            });

            /* $(document).on('click', '.add-markers', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                addMarkers();
            }); */

            function getcurrentposition()
            {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(position, status) {
                    if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                        var clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                        $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': clientPosition, 'bounds': true});
                        $('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', 'Circle', { 
                            'strokeWeight': 0, 
                            'fillColor': "#008595", 
                            'fillOpacity': 0.25, 
                            'center': clientPosition, 
                            'radius': 15, 
                            'clickable': false 
                        });
                    }
                });

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">

            <div data-role="content">   
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" >
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:500px"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Logcat

```
04-04 04:53:07.952: D/CordovaLog(1665): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
04-04 04:53:07.952: I/chromium(1665): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/my_current_location.html (1)
04-04 04:53:08.182: D/Cordova(1665): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/my_current_location.html)
04-04 04:53:08.182: D/Cordova(1665): Trying to fire onNativeReady
04-04 04:53:08.202: D/DroidGap(1665): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
04-04 04:53:08.202: D/DroidGap(1665): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/my_current_location.html)
```

Comment: Have you checked the javascript console? Any errors?

Comment: I have checked my logcat ...I am developing in Eclipse ..see the edits

Comment: That message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined` is comming after your function `getcurrentposition()` is started. So Dr.Molle is right.

Comment: I have added that method in js ..now that uncaught type error has gone but nothing to display

Comment: Add this js file<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.map.extensions.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jquery.ui.map` doesn't have a method `getCurrentPosition` , you must implement it on your own.

See http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/Examples#Example_get_user_position for an example

---

**<edit>**

The linked example seems to be wrong, at least it's wrong for this version of jquery.ui.map

Use:

```
( function($) {

    $.extend($.ui.gmap.prototype, {

            /**
             * Gets the current position
             * @a: function(status, position)
             * @b:object, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMGeoPositionOptions
             */
            getCurrentPosition: function(callback, geoPositionOptions) {
        if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition ( 
                function(result) {
                    callback(result, 'OK');
                }, 
                function(error) {
                    callback(null, error);
                }, 
                geoPositionOptions 
            );  
        } else {
            callback(null, 'NOT_SUPPORTED');
        }
    }

    });

  } (jQuery) );
```

But you also may load the existing `jquery.ui.map.extensions.js` as suggested by  Ved

**Additionally:**
You must also include http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.map.overlays.js , this will implement the `addShape`-method

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/rd4Xt/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/rd4Xt/)
**</edit>**

Comment: I have tried the code in the link ..I have created the method  jquery.ui.map.extensions.js  and jquery.ui.map.extensions.min.js..but now no ajax loader and nothing to display

Answer (score 0):

Add this javascript file also..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.map.extensions.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have added that..but nothing happened.

Comment: what nothing happened ?

Comment: I am trying in my device Nexus 7 tab..I am getting other mapviews the problem is with geolocation ..when I added geolocation codes I am just getting a frame